# Python Unittest, Inheritance, and Member Variable Propagation

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm using Python 2.6. Let's say I have 2 classes:

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_a(self):
        print 'test_a'
        self.random_variable = random_string()
        print self.random_variable

class SubTest1(BaseTest):
    def test_b(self):
        print 'test_b'
        print self.random_variable
```

Where random_string() returns a randomly generated 20 character string.

I'd like to be able to access `self.random_variable` in `SubTest1.test_b`. Right now, `self.random_variable` in test_b is undefined.

When `BaseTest` runs, it would have its own unique random string, but when `SubTest1` runs, it would have the same string generated in `BaseTest`. The output for all of this would ideally look something like this:

```
test_a
dgkwgmhkiszvmlhceved

test_a
akvjkskdmhfygsysgjci
test_b
akvjkskdmhfygsysgjci
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

One of the principles of unit testing is that every test should be isolated from, and independent of, every other test.  If you have test work that you want done in more than one test, then put it in a helper function, and call that function from the tests:

```
class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def do_common_stuff(self):
        self.random_variable = random_string()
        #... do more stuff you want in more than one test ...

    def test_a(self):
        self.do_common_stuff()

    def test_b(self):
        self.do_common_stuff()
        #... do more stuff ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define the variable in the `setUp` method which runs before each test case (so that's then different for each test):

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.random_variable = random_string()

    def test_a(self):
        print 'test_a'
        print self.random_variable
```

If you want it to be the same you'll need to use `setUpClass`:

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        self.random_variable = random_string()

    def test_a(self):
        print 'test_a'
        print self.random_variable
```

Note that marking `setUpClass` with `@classmethod` is important as it turns the method from a regular method into a class method (which receives the class rather than the instance as first argument).

Comment: Unfortunately, setUpClass is a method that was added in 2.7. I'm using 2.6.